# Retrieve properties from nested collections of a type with Fluent Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to create a way for adding into a collection, properties selected from a type using Fluent syntax. I currently have the following:

**SelectablePropertiesBuilder**

```
public class SelectablePropertiesBuilder<T>
{

    #region Fields

    private const char SEPARATOR_CHAR = ',';

    private List<PropertyInfo> _propertiesSelected;

    #endregion


    #region Properties

    public char GetSeparator => SEPARATOR_CHAR;

    public int Count => _propertiesSelected.Count;

    #endregion


    #region Constructor

    internal SelectablePropertiesBuilder()
    {
        _propertiesSelected = new List<PropertyInfo>();
    }

    public static T InitBuilder() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    #endregion


    #region Public methods

    public void AddSelected(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        _propertiesSelected.Add(propertyInfo);
    }

    public string FormatSelection()
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        IteratePropertiesForBuilder(stringBuilder);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    #endregion


    #region Private methods

    private void IteratePropertiesForBuilder(StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        int currentIndex = 1, totalCount = _propertiesSelected.Count;

        foreach (var prop in _propertiesSelected)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(prop.Name);

            if (currentIndex < totalCount)
                stringBuilder.Append(SEPARATOR_CHAR);

            currentIndex++;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

**Extension methods**

```
    public static SelectablePropertiesBuilder<T> SelectProperty<T, TProperty>(this T objectSource, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
    {
        var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(navigationPropertyPath);

        var builder = new SelectablePropertiesBuilder<T>();
        builder.AddSelected(propertyInfo);

        return builder;
    }

    public static SelectablePropertiesBuilder<T> ThenSelectProperty<T, TProperty>(this SelectablePropertiesBuilder<T> builder, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
    {
        var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(navigationPropertyPath);

        builder.AddSelected(propertyInfo);

        return builder;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
    {
        var member = (MemberExpression)navigationPropertyPath.Body;
        var propertyName = member.Member.Name;
        var propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo { Name = propertyName };

        return propertyInfo;
    }
```

**Working full UnitTest method:**

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void Given_ExternalTypeWithNestedCollection_WhenFormatSelectionInvoked_ThenStringFormattedRetrived()
    {
        var propertiesFormatted = SelectablePropertiesBuilder<TestClass>.InitBuilder()
           .SelectProperty(x => x.TestPropertyStr)
           .ThenSelectProperty(x => x.TestPropertyInt)
           .FormatSelection();

        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertiesFormatted));
        Assert.IsTrue(propertiesFormatted.LastIndexOf(',') != propertiesFormatted.Length);
    }
```

Well, this is working now, but, I need to select properties inside nested collections. Currently I can't do that, and I'm blocked of how can I add this functionalty by using this same syntax.

¿Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

***PD: Full repository of the implementation inside ChustaSoft.Common NuGet [here](https://github.com/Xelit3/CommonNET):***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Finally I found a way for achieving my purpose by using a singleton and an inherited SelectablePropertiesBuilder. I've also improved the syntax, you can see the full implementation here:***

- **Builder**: https://github.com/ChustaSoft/CommonNET/blob/master/ChustaSoft.Common/Utilities/SelectablePropertiesBuilder.cs
- **Extension methods**: https://github.com/ChustaSoft/CommonNET/blob/master/ChustaSoft.Common/Helpers/SelectablePropertiesBuilderHelper.cs
- **Singleton**: https://github.com/ChustaSoft/CommonNET/blob/master/ChustaSoft.Common/Models/SelectablePropertiesContext.cs
- **Test**: https://github.com/ChustaSoft/CommonNET/blob/master/ChustaSoft.Common.UnitTest/TestServices/SelectablePropertiesBuilderHelperUnitTest.cs